# Is it possible to implement a Firefox add-on in XUL containing 2 sidebars?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, firefox-sidebar

I'm implementing a Firefox add-on which is a sidebar coded in XUL. Now I would like to implement a second sidebar that I could display at the same time than the first sidebar in the same add-on. So basically I would like to have one left sidebar and one right sidebar on the same window.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use built-in XUL sidebar, AFAIK there is no such possibility as it uses the same (built once at startup time) XUL element to display all sidebars. You may try to clone this element as XUL is very similar to DOM, but many chances that it will break some functionality in browser.

Still, you are not limited to using only built-in sidebar. Try to simulate it if it is possible solution to you.